# Web Scraping : Getting HTML source generated from JSP using Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to get the dynamically generated tables from this page (http://xbrl.cninfo.com.cn/XBRL/allinfo.jsp?stkid=000410&getyear=2012&nowpage=Info.jsp&reportType=GB0110) using Python. I have tried using mechanize, selenium with the PhantomJS webdriver modules but to no avail. Following is a part of code I used :

```
url = 'http://xbrl.cninfo.com.cn/XBRL/allinfo.jsp?stkid=000410&getyear=2012&nowpage=Info.jsp&reportType=GB0110'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
driver.get(url)
content = driver.page_source
# Used BeautifulSoup after this to get all the table content within the iframe tag but it's source is some jsp page.
```

I am new to web scraping so don't know how to scrape dynamically created content. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the data you want is placed in iframe.
Try this

```
driver.get(url)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe"))
content = driver.page_source
```